# Typealias inside Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, protocols, type-alias

I have a typealias inside my protocol. Do I have to add the typealias to the conforming type or is there an alternative? My goal is to declare the typealias once.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    typealias Closure = (T) -> Void
    var blocks: [Closure] { get set }
}

struct SomeStruct<T>: SomeProtocol {
    typealias Closure = (T) -> Void // <- do I have to add this?
    var blocks: [Closure]  
}
```

FYI this works. Im just looking for a simpler implementation of the typealias.

Comment: Well, have you tried removing it an seeing what happens?

Comment: Im asking if I use a typealias, whether I need to include it again.

Answer (score -1):

You don't necessarily need the `typealias` in the `struct` -- it can be inferred:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    typealias Closure = (T) -> Void
    var blocks: [Closure] { get set }
}

struct SomeStruct<T>: SomeProtocol {
    var blocks: [(T) -> Void]
}

let someStruct = SomeStruct<Int>(blocks: [{someInt in print(someInt)}])
someStruct.blocks[0](123)
```

Comment: What do you mean?  Try that example in a playground.  You don't need to use `typealias` in the struct.

Comment: ur using `var blocks: [(T) -> Void]` instead of `var blocks: [Closure]`. It would work if I used it like that but thats not the question.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im trying to find a way to continue using the typealias without having to define it twice

Comment: Ah.  Well, that's really a different question.